# Tengo este error en consola: AttributeError: 'Adulto' object has no attribute 'nombre'

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de crear una herencia de una clase en python y me surge el siguiente error:

```
AttributeError: 'Adulto' object has no attribute 'nombre'
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
# Clase padre #

class Persona():
  texto = ''
  def __init__(self, nombre):
      self.nombre = nombre

  def saludar(self):
      self.texto = f"Hola, mi nombre es: {self.nombre}."
      return self.texto

persona1 = Persona("Juan")

# Herencia de clase Persona() #

class Adulto(Persona):
  def __init__(self,nombre): # El parametro nombre no lo reconoce #
      Persona.__init__(self.nombre)

adulto1 = Adulto("Juan")
print(type(adulto1))
```

Mi intención es que me muestre en consola: `'__main__.Adulto'` (que adulto1 es un objeto de la clase `Adulto()`).

Comment: no debería de ser `Persona.__init__(self,nombre)`?? por que dentro de tu clase `adulto` no tienes ningún atributo llamado nombre y `Persona` aun no está inicializado

Comment: A que te referís a que `Persona` aún no está inicializado? @Christian

Comment: de que aun no hay una instancia de `Persona`

Comment: entendiste lo que te dije?

Comment: Si, pero no está instanciado en persona1 la clase "Persona()"? Si hago el print `print(type(persona1))` me sale en consola: `class '__main__.Persona'` @Christian

Comment: `persona1` es distinto de `Persona`. `persiona1` es un objeto de tipo `Persona` (por eso al hacer `type`, sale la clase Persona) y `Persona` es una clase. No se si entrar más a profundidad, si quieres puedo hacer una respuesta.

Comment: Encontré una solución sabiendo como funciona `__init__` y la clase herencia. Simplemente cuando se crea la clase hijo no es necesario pasar los mismos parámetros, sacando ambos `__init__` e iniciando otro constructor directamente en la clase hijo, no pasa ningun error. Gracias por la ayuda! tu respuesta me hizo dar dirección a la solución! @Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error en está en la línea

```
 Persona.__init__(self.nombre)
```

Al llegar a esta línea, el objeto en creación no tiene ningún atributo declarado, por lo que `self.nombre` es `None`.

Tu intención es tomar el nombre recibido por `Adulto.__init__` y usarlo para inicializar `Persona`. La manera correcta de hacerlo es

```
class Adulto(Persona):
  def __init__(self,nombre): # El parametro nombre no lo reconoce #
      Persona.__init__(self, nombre)
```

La llamada a `Persona.__init__` requiere dos parámetros: el objeto que estas inicializando (`self`) y el nombre.

#### Demo

```
# Clase padre #

class Persona():
  texto = ''
  def __init__(self, nombre):
      self.nombre = nombre

  def saludar(self):
      self.texto = f"Hola, mi nombre es: {self.nombre}."
      return self.texto

persona1 = Persona("Juan")

# Herencia de clase Persona() #

class Adulto(Persona):
  def __init__(self,nombre): # El parametro nombre no lo reconoce #
      Persona.__init__(self, nombre)

adulto1 = Adulto("Juan")
print(type(adulto1))
```

produce:

```
<class '__main__.Adulto'>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Si es totalmente correcto muchas gracias por las respuesta! @Candid Moe